# Java - String value is not getting saved in String array

Tags: java, arrays

In the below code;

```
stepOrExpected[i][k] = "Step";
System.out.println(stepOrExpected[i][k]);
```

by using loop with i and k, I am saving values in stepOrExpected (two dimensional array). Problem here is String is not getting saved. if I print right after I assigned value to stepOrExpected, it is printing null.

Moreover, if I print i and k, both the values are correct.

Please suggest the why String is not getting saved in two dimensional array.

I have pasted my code below, problem I am facing is in

```
(if (StepLstNode.getNodeName().equals("Step"))
{
stepOrExpected[i][k] = "Step";)
```

Actual Code:

```
if (ModulenameLstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
{
    NodeList TCLst = ModulenameLstNode.getChildNodes();

    TCCount = docInput.getElementsByTagName("TC").getLength();
    System.out.println(TCCount);
    TCID = new String[TCCount];
    //TCDepend = new String[TCCount];
    TCDescription = new String[TCCount];
    stepCountInATCOfModule = new int[TCCount];
    ExpectedResult = new String[TCCount];
    ActualResult_Pass = new String[TCCount];
    ActualResult_Fail = new String[TCCount];
    //Result.XMLCreator();
    int i=0;
    stepOrExpected = new String [TCCount][100];
    Action = new String [TCCount][100];
    RefObj = new String [TCCount][100];
    Val = new String [TCCount][100];

    for (int TC = 0; TC < TCLst.getLength(); TC++) 
    {

        int k=0;
        Node TCLstNode = TCLst.item(TC);

        if (TCLstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
        {
            System.out.println(TCLstNode.getNodeName());

            TCID[i] = ObjectType.getAttribute(TCLstNode,"Id");
            //TCDepend[i] = ObjectType.getAttribute(TCLstNode,"Depend");
            TCDescription[i] = ObjectType.getAttribute(TCLstNode,"Description");

            NodeList StepLst = TCLstNode.getChildNodes();


            System.out.println(StepLst.getLength());
            for (int Step = 0; Step < StepLst.getLength(); Step++) 
            {
                Node StepLstNode = StepLst.item(Step);

                if (StepLstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                {

                    if (StepLstNode.getNodeName().equals("Step"))
                    {
                        stepOrExpected[i][k] = "Step";
                        Action[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"Action");
                        RefObj[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"RefObj");
                        Val[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"Val");
                        stepCountInTC++;
                        k++;
                        System.out.println(i);
                        System.out.println(k);
                        System.out.println(ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"Action"));
                        System.out.println(stepOrExpected[i][k]);
                    }
                    else if (StepLstNode.getNodeName().equals("Expected"))
                    {
                        stepOrExpected[i][k] = "Expected";
                        Action[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"ExpAction");
                        RefObj[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"ExpTarget");
                        Val[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"ExpVal");
                        stepCountInTC++;
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (StepLstNode.getNodeName().equals("ExpectedResult"))
                    {
                        ExpectedResult [i] = StepLstNode.getTextContent();
                    }
                    else if (StepLstNode.getNodeName().equals("ActualResult_Pass"))
                    {
                        ActualResult_Pass [i] = StepLstNode.getTextContent();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ActualResult_Fail [i] = StepLstNode.getTextContent();
                    }

                }//Step NodeType

            }//Step for


            stepCountInATCOfModule[i] = stepCountInTC;
            i++;
            stepCountInTC = 0;

        }//TC if

    }//TC for
}
```

Comment: In theory, this should work. Can you give the context that this is in, or at least runnable code with the nested loops?

Comment: not a clear code snippet to say anything

Comment: Please post the entire relevant code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707869/can-anyone-explain-how-to-initialize-two-dimensional-array  .Try to check this if this is your problem

Comment: Your real code changes `k` between setting it and printing it... so it sets one element, then prints a different one.

Comment: You're incrementing `k`, `k++`  before the print

Comment: Thank you all for your time, it is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is `k++;`. You are incrementing `k` before printing it to the console. So, modify your code as following,

```
stepOrExpected[i][k] = "Step";
Action[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"Action");
RefObj[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"RefObj");
Val[i][k] = ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"Val");   
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(k);
System.out.println(ObjectType.getAttribute(StepLstNode,"Action"));
System.out.println(stepOrExpected[i][k]);
stepCountInTC++; //moved counter
k++; //moved counter
```

Everything should work, as expected.