# Issue in initializing an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I faced a null pointer exception when I tried to retrieve an object from a normal array. First I initialize the array with 10 `Line` objects and then set the values of each object inside the array. But when I retrieve the values of any objects, I found it to be 0's. Why does that happen?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LineArrayLimt extends Applet
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    int width, height;
    int x, y, lineCounter;    // the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the box
    int mx, my;  // the most recently recorded mouse coordinates
    int new_mx;
    int new_my;
    Thread th;
    boolean isMouseDragging = false, isStored;
    Line[] lines = new Line[10];

    class Line {

        Line() {
        }

        Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            this.x1 = x1;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
        }
        private int x1, y1, x2, y2;

        public void setX1(int x) {
            this.x1 = x;
        }

        public void setY1(int y) {
            this.y1 = y;
        }

        public void setX2(int x) {
            this.x2 = x;
        }

        public void setY2(int y) {
            this.y2 = y;
        }

        public int getX1() {
            return x1;
        }

        public int getY1() {
            return y1;
        }

        public int getX2() {
            return x2;
        }

        public int getY2() {
            return y2;
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i] = new Line();
        }

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("-----------------Mouse Pressed------------------------");
        mx = e.getX();
        my = e.getY();



    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("-----------------Mouse Released------------------------");
        if (isMouseDragging) {
            if (lineCounter != lines.length - 1) {
                lines[lineCounter].setX1(mx);
                lines[lineCounter].setY1(my);
                lines[lineCounter].setX2(new_mx);
                lines[lineCounter].setY2(new_my);
                lineCounter++;
                if (lines[lineCounter] != null) {
                    System.out.println("-----------------First Object------------------------" + lines[lineCounter].getX1() + " " + lines[lineCounter].getY1() + " " + lines[lineCounter].getX2() + " " + lines[lineCounter].getY1());
                }


            }

        }
        isMouseDragging = false;

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("-----------------Mouse Dragged------------------------");
        isMouseDragging = true;
        new_mx = e.getX();
        new_my = e.getY();
        if (new_mx <= 35) {
            new_mx = 35;
        }
        if (new_mx > width - 40) {
            new_mx = width - 40;
        }
        if (new_my > height - 40) {
            new_my = height - 40;
        }
        if (new_my < 35) {
            new_my = 35;
        }
        repaint();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("-----------------Line No." + lineCounter + " is inside paint------------------------");
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        if (isMouseDragging) {
            System.out.println("-----------------Paint while dragging------------------------");
            g.drawLine(mx, my, new_mx, new_my);
            if (lineCounter != lines.length - 1) {
                //if(lines[lineCounter]!=null){
                g.drawLine(lines[lineCounter].getX1(), lines[lineCounter].getY1(), lines[lineCounter].getX2(), lines[lineCounter].getX2());
                System.out.println("*************" + lines[lineCounter].getX1() + lines[lineCounter].getY1() + lines[lineCounter].getX2() + lines[lineCounter].getX2());
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use trycatch function at the marked line

Comment: @goravine: Absolutely not. You should almost *never* catch NullPointerException deliberately.

Comment: It's very hard to read your code because it's so badly formatted. Please put more effort into writing your question in a way which is as easy to read as possible. (I'm sure you could also cut the example down significantly.)

Comment: Here is some insight for you to navigate over NPE [article1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception), [article2](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.sg/2012/01/javalangnullpointerexception-how-to.html?m=1)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922677/nullpointerexception-when-creating-an-array-of-object for a "minimal test case" of similar NPE behavior (I would use a List as suggested by Jon, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in init you're initializing `lines` to an array of 10 null references:

```
lines = new Line[10];
```

Then in `paint` you're using that null reference:

```
if (lineCounter != lines.length - 1) {
    g.drawLine(lines[lineCounter].getX1(),
               lines[lineCounter].getY1(),
               lines[lineCounter].getX2(),
               lines[lineCounter].getY2());
}
```

`lines.length` will *always* be 10 - it isn't the number of non-null references in the array. It's not the number of lines you've added, or anything like that. (It's not clear what your `if` condition is trying to achieve, to be honest.)

You'd be better off using a `List<Line>` instead. Then in `paint` you could just use:

```
for (Line line : lines) {
    ...
}
```

... and in `mouseReleased` you'd just use:

```
lines.add(new Line(...));
```

Also note that there's no reason for `Line` to be an inner class. Either make it a static nested class, or a top-level (non-nested) class.

Comment: or explicitly initialize it in a loop. [lines[i] = new Line();] (i varies from 0 to 9)

Comment: @TJ-: I can't see how that would work usefully, as before the user has drawn any lines, there just aren't any which should be drawn...

Comment: oh, my bad. I didn't read the question, I was just referring to making use of lines = new Line[10];

Comment: ok, but what's the problem in initializing the array with 10 elements of type Line in init method, in mouseReleased i added elements to the array so why it still holds NULLS? i edit the code, i think that the problem is that paint is accessing a null reference only in the first time the applet started, so i add an extra condition to paint in order to access the array elements

Comment: @Eslam: In `init()` you're **not** initializing the array with 10 `Line` references. You're creating an array which initially holds 10 `null` references. You *could* create 10 `Line` objects, but you don't really want to draw any lines, so it wouldn't make sense to do so. Fundamentally I think you need to revisit array creation behaviour - but I'd also strongly suggest using a list instead anyway...

Comment: @Jon Skeet so how to initialize the array with 10 line objects instead of these null references?

Comment: @Eslam: You'd call `new Line(...)` and assign a value to each element of the array. But as I keep saying, you shouldn't do that. I'm not sure why you're not taking my advice to use a `List<Line>` instead, and only add lines when you need to...

Comment: ok, i already do that but all the objects inside the array still contains 0's, i tried it before with array list and i want to do it alos with the normal array to notice the difference, please check above code i will update it in a minute

Comment: @Eslam: Do *not* just change the code in your question, as otherwise all the existing answer won't make sense. But yes, if you create new `Line` objects with 0 co-ordinates, of course they'll contain 0 co-ordinates. What did you expect to happen? It sounds like you need to take a step back and work out what you actually want the array to contain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the line is indeed added to the array in `mouseReleased`?

Comment: What I meant is that if for some reason the conditions are always false in the method, than the elements of the array will stay null. Just a very basic sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are filling the array only in `mouseReleased()` function and `paint` method doesn't wait for mouse to release. So when the mouse is not released, `paint()` method tries to draw line.

you just uncomment your check `if(lines[lineCounter]!=null)` and try, it should work.

If you want to achieve anything else, let us know