# NullPointerException coordinate array

Tags: constructor, nullpointerexception, coordinates

To make the snake game, I need to position the snake at the beginning at (0,0), (1.0). I'm working with a coordinate class and a snake class. In the constructor of the coordinate class I set all x and y values to 0. I created an array with coordinates and I want to set the first 2 coordinates manually **(method startPositionSnake)** because it's the starting position. This is when I get a nullpointerexception. I don't get why this happens because all coordinates are (0,0) by default. (under the screenshots is the used code)
[image]
[image]

code:

```
package Snake;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import ui.Event;
import ui.SnakeUserInterface;
import ui.UserInterfaceFactory;

public class Coordinate {

    public static final int WIDTH = 26;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 26;
    int x;
    int y;

    Coordinate() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    void locateApple() {
        Random random = new Random();
        x = random.nextInt(WIDTH);
        y = random.nextInt(HEIGHT);
    }
}
package Snake;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import ui.Event;
import ui.SnakeUserInterface;
import ui.UserInterfaceFactory;

public class Snake {

    int lengthOfSnake;
    Coordinate headOfSnake = new Coordinate();
    Coordinate[] snakePosition = new Coordinate[20];
    
    Snake() {
        lengthOfSnake = 2;
    }
    
    void startPositionSnake() {
        snakePosition[0].x = 1;
        snakePosition[0].y = 0;
        snakePosition[1].x = 0;
        snakePosition[1].y = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object arrays are filled with null values by default. To fill them with the coordinates you have to loop through the array and fill them (see *[NullPointerException when Creating an Array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922677/nullpointerexception-when-creating-an-array-of-objects)*)