# java.lang.NullPointerException even though it's instanciated as global var

Tags: java, class, pointers, netbeans

my problem is easy normally but i just don't see where is the problem.
-i am declaring an array of a class as a global variable that i reuse in multiple functions inside this other class.
the class instantiated is:

```
 public class Service {
      int numticketsin;
            String name="mi";
            int[] perhour={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            
            int moyenneticketperday;
            int[] moyenneticketperdayperhour={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            public Service(){}
}
```

global var:

```
Service[] services=new Service[10];
```

the function where i use try to fill the array:

```
 public void getnamesofservices(){
        int x=0;
        Connection conn=db.java_db();
    
        try {   
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            
                String qry = "SELECT  service_name from service ";
 
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
                int i=0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                        String namee=rs.getString("service_name");
                        System.out.println(namee);

                        services[i].name = namee;
                   i++;
                }
                conn.close();
                
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
            {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex);
        }
        
    }
```

the error:

```
''' Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot assign field "name" because "this.services[i]" is null
    at com.mycompany.stats.NewJFrame.getnamesofservices(NewJFrame.java:195)
    at com.mycompany.stats.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:122)
    at com.mycompany.stats.Main.main(Main.java:16)'''
```

thank you in advance!!

Comment: So which line is line 195? (I'd also strongly advise that you start following Java naming conventions, e.g. `getNamesOfServices` - or just `getServiceNames` instead of `getnamesofservices`, as well as a better name than `java_db`.

Comment: `new Service[10]` means you _allocate_ a 10 elements array of `Service` instances that are initially `null`, but it does not mean you initialize each element, therefore all of the elements are `null` after the allocation. Seriously, why not debug it first and initialize the array properly?

Comment: [NullPointerException when Creating an Array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922677/nullpointerexception-when-creating-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Service[] services=new Service[10];
```

This means you created and array with 10 positions, but all those positions are empty (meaning they have `null` inside each and every position of the array).

So, when trying `services[i].name` you get the `NullPointerException` because `services[i]` is `null`.

There are plenty of ways to do the initialization, that depends on your business cases. But just to name two possibilities:

1. Initialize it at the declaration:

```
Service services[] = new Service[] { 
   new Service(),new Service(), new Service(), new Service(),new Service(),
   new Service(),new Service(), new Service(), new Service(),new Service()
};
```

2. Or just before using it, in case you are not overriding it:

```
services[i] = new Service();
services[i].name = namee;
```